# Background image SVG animation stopped working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Not sure when or how, but the loading svg animation i was using is no longer working on Chrome (still works on safari and firefox for example).

[Here's a code sample for the problem](https://jsbin.com/bopefelufa/1/edit?)

```html
    <svg width='64px' height='64px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="uil-default"><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(0 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(36 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.1s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(72 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.2s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(108 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.3s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(144 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.4s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(180 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.5s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(216 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(252 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.7s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(288 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.8s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(324 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.9s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect></svg>
```

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe it is a caching issue in chrome. I'm not sure because for me it is working fine also after a several tries. Maybe it would be a good idea to share you're console because chrome does sometimes got issues with unsecure URLs.

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: @RobertLongson i was not sure this was actually a chrome thing, it's not that uncommon for browser implementations to differ slighly from specs, so i could be missing something in valid spec html/css for the svg animation to actually work.

Comment: Chrome bug? Didn't work in v67, but worked again when I just updated to v68.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your chrome to the latest version(v68) and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

It works fine when you do not use the svg as background, but actually put the svg-code in your html.

```html
<svg width='64px' height='64px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="uil-default"><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(0 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(36 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.1s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(72 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.2s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(108 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.3s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(144 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.4s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(180 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.5s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(216 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(252 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.7s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(288 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.8s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect><rect  x='46' y='35' width='8' height='30' rx='5' ry='5' fill='#666666' transform='rotate(324 50 50) translate(0 -30)'>  <animate attributeName='opacity' from='1' to='0' dur='1s' begin='0.9s' repeatCount='indefinite'/></rect></svg>
```

Comment: yeah, but that's not a reusable way to do it, nor will it be easy to switch loading svgs that way.